# MVC post not adding values to model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple edit form for a user model but when I post back, none of the hidden input values are being applied to model and I'm not sure why this is happening.

My Razor:

```
@model CMS.Core.Models.UserProfile

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset class="normalForm">
        <legend>User Profile</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)

        <div class="formRow">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { @class = "textbox" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="formRow">
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "textbox" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="buttonRow"><input type="submit" value="Save" class="button" /></div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

My Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserProfile user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            user.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

UserProfile class:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; private set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter an email address")]
    [StringLength(350)]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }


    [StringLength(100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

If I try `user.UserId` it returns zero (as it is an int) but if I try `Request["UserId"]` it returns the correct value so the value is being posted correctly - just not added into the `UserProfile` model.  Does anyone know why this is happening or what I can do to solve it

Thanks

Comment: How is generated html look like for the hidden field? Also can you post your UserProfile model?

Comment: <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field UserId must be a number." data-val-required="The UserId field is required." id="UserId" name="UserId" type="hidden" value="4" />

Comment: The generated HTML looks fine. So can you update your post with the definition of your `UserProfile` class?

Comment: Do you have a parameter named UserId in your routes?

Comment: no I haven't touched the routes file, userprofile class added

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `DefaultModelBinder` only able to bind **public properties**.

Change your  property setter to public and it should work fine:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int UserId { get; set; }
```

If you can't do that you will need create a custom model binder which deals with private setters.

However as a better approach instead of using your `UserProfile` directly. Create a `UserProfileViewModel` where your `UserId` is public and use that in your View and Controller action. In this case you need to map between your `UserProfile` and the `UserProfileViewModel` but there are good tools exists for that task like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Comment: This is the answer. Can't use **private set** in this context.

Answer (score 1):

As @nemesev said, the accessor properties on your Model properties need to be **public**.

To save you from having to hack away at your database class in order to make model binding work, you should really create a Model for that class, then you don't need to use the DTO in the view (which isn't ideal).